# C# - Substring sum using tokens to identify values

Tags: c#, string, sum, substring

What I would like to achieve is the following. I have a string which could be in the following format (just an example the actual string could be completely random):

```
01005010050
```

The above string is broken down into the following fields:

```
0 100 50 100 50
```

What I would like to achieve is to place the sum of the last 4 fields into the first 0 field. I do have the opportunity to decorate the string with tokens or something which can be used to identify where the fields lie within the string, i.e.

```
[£+]0[£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-]
```

Then I would use a regex to get the inner values from the start and end tokens. I would need some way of identifying which of the fields is the master so I was just going to use another token:

```
[*][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-]
```

Then I could just go through the found inner strings, convert them and add them. Then on the original string remove the start [£+] and end [£-] tokens and replace [*] with the total calculated. I think this would work but the problem comes in that I could have multiple totals per string.

```
[£+][*][£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-]\r\n
[£+][*][£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-][£+]100[£-][£+]50[£-]
```

So I was thinking to add some kind of ID to the field:

```
ID1[*][£+]ID1|100[£-][£+]ID1|50[£-][£+]ID1|100[£-][£+]ID1|50[£-]\r\n
ID2[*][£+]ID2|100[£-][£+]ID2|50[£-][£+]ID2|100[£-][£+]ID2|50[£-]
```

So then you would use a regex to split the string. Split the found inner strings on the pipe (|) so then the first value would be the key and the second the value. Add all these to a dictionary or something. Then you would have to go through each key in the dictionary and add all the totals, remove the tokens from the original string and replace "Key[*]" with the found total for that key.

The process is complicated more by the fact that another field could hold the total of totals. I just wanted to get clarification first that this is a logical way of doing this and I am not over complicating things when there is a simple solution. Just to clarify the format of the string could be totally random i.e.

```
abc1000cde50 where fields are:
abc 100 0 c d e 50 (total placed in field 3 from 2 + 7)
```

The reason why I have the opportunity to decorate the fields is that this string is built from an XML file where I could have an attribute stating this is a total field and this is the master. The reason why I cant simply add the values while building the string is that a number of other calculations are carried out first, including calculating what the values actually are (i.e this field is in the range of 0 - 500). I was just going to calculate the totals at the end just before returning the finished built string. The way the code is structured I lose the ability to have the fields split up hence placing tokens to show where the fields lie within the string and being able to calculate the totals that way.

Comment: did you even read that?!

Comment: @AppDeveloper According to his well defined question , I think he tried quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adresses only the first part of the question!

Assuming that you split the string after a 0 and before something != 0:

```
{
    string s = "01005010050";

    var ls = new List<int>();

    for (int n = 0; n < s.Length - 1; n++)
    {
        if ((int)s[n] == 48 && (int)s[n + 1] != 48) // 48 = Ascii(0)
        {
            s = s.Insert(n + 1, ";");
        }
    }

    ls = s.Split(';').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();

    for (int n = 1; n < ls.Count(); n++)
    {
        ls[0] += ls[n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking of the solution as a process of replacing fields in the input string with other computed fields. You say things like "What I would like to achieve is to place the sum of the last 4 fields into the first 0 field" and "... remove the tokens from the original string and replace "Key[*]" with  ...". If I was trying to program this I would think of the process in three steps (1) read in the data and store it in some format convenient for doing computations (2) do the required computations and store the results in some way (3) produce the output string in the required format.